# Reviews red dot with nothing to do

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues

After I finished to do all my reviews, triage and late answers in Stack Overflow, I get the red dot symbol each 4-5 minutes, and when I click on it, I get the notification I got nothing to review. When I refresh the red dot gone, but come back after 4-5 minutes, with the same behavior. What is it?
[image]

Comment: The red-dot is site-wide, not per user. status-bydesign

Comment: @rene What is that mean? Why it's appear and disappear every few of minutes?

Comment: that is a common problem on all SE sites, it seems that when there are enough reviews the dot appears, and it doesn't matter if you can do something  about it

Comment: even when you are banned, which is more than anointing

Comment: The red-dot shows if any of the review queues have enough tasks in it over a threshold. On SO, given its size, its easy to have both enough reviewers to quickly resolve pending tasks while on the other hand new ones get queued up due to new posts/moderation/curation. Review tasks are sourced in batches and these run on 5 and/or 15 minute schedule. That makes it can easily resonate between on and off. Notice that the user, aka you, is not part of determining whether a red dot is shown. We're not that important to be correctly informed.

Comment: it is urgently time to renew this

Comment: If it annoys you, you can block the icon. It just leads to stackoverflow.com/review which is pretty easy to remember.

Comment: You've completed the maximum number of reviews that you can perform per day. Therefore, you cannot do any more reviewing in the review queues today. Check back tomorrow. The red dot just means that there are items in the queue to be reviewed. The indicator doesn't take into account your specific eligibility. (Note: when I say "day", I mean the UTC day.)

Comment: Five pages worth of "No action needed" and "Look OK".  There's a bigger problem here...

Comment: On stack overflow, the rest dot means nothing to my browser; it changes like the weather. It's on other sites that it works, but with many bugs.

Comment: The state changes quickly on Stack Overflow. That is to be expected. SO is a large site, so when the review queues fill up and the red dot comes on, *lots* of users see it, go do some reviews, and the queues quickly empty to below the warning threshold level. Then the dot goes off.