# What is the red circle on review queue for?

Tags: support, review-queues, design

Sometimes, I'd see the red circle and when I click it there'd be nothing to review as in the image below:

[image]

But sometimes, there'd be no red circle but when I click the tab, there'd be posts to review as in the image below:

[image]

In my mind, it should be notifying me to check out the review queue to review posts but it doesn't seem to do that at the moment. What is it for?

Comment: However, for this case, looks like the user is currently review banned since it's showing "There are no review queues available to you" instead.

Comment: The user who asked this question is not currently suspended from review. In fact, they've *never* been suspended from review.

Comment: @CodyGray hmm, strange. Because that's what I concluded from [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356873/2821954). Edit: oh, never mind, [the user has used all their daily review quota](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403553/reviews-red-dot-with-nothing-to-do?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment813548_403553).